# Webpack error for 3rd party react module (effector)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, effector

**EDIT:** I gave up with my own Webpack setup and just used `react-scripts` and now it compiles just fine. So must have been my Webpack/Babel setup, though still can't find out what

I'm trying to play around with the module [effector](https://github.com/zerobias/effector), which has a React binding [effector-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/effector-react). I copy pasted a basic (working) code sandbox example, but I'm getting a webpack error which makes me think my build configuration isn't right.

My simple component is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { useStore } from "effector-react";

import { s_counter } from "stores/counter";

function Count () {
  const counter = useStore(s_counter);

  return ( <div>{counter}</div> );
};

export default Count;
```

and my effector counter store is as follows:

```
import { createStore, createEvent } from "effector";

// Store
const s_counter = createStore(0);

export { s_counter };
```

I think the issue is with my Webpack/Babel config, which are as follows:

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/src/dist',
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
      stores: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/stores/'),
    },
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

I'm using webpack 4, and when I build by just running `webpack` my app doesn't load and I get the console error:

```
effector.es.js:35 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object../node_modules/effector/effector.es.js (bundle.js:109)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (effector-react.es.js:13)
    at Module../node_modules/effector-react/effector-react.es.js (bundle.js:97)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (Count.jsx:4)
    at Module../src/components/Count.jsx (bundle.js:311)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at eval (App.jsx:4)
    at Module../src/components/App.jsx (bundle.js:299)
```

The actual error is caused by importing things from `effector-react`, specifically this line:

```
import { useStore } from "effector-react";
```

doesn't matter what module I import from `effector-react`, I get that console error. Any ideas for what's going wrong are welcome.

EDIT: same kind of problem if importing from `effector` itself too

Answer (score 1):

Tested on npm@6.4.1, webpack4.30.0 & node@10.13.0

Try this,

Did you download `effector` separately as a npm dependency. 
I believe you are not able to resolve this module specifically.

I tried using the same modules using.

```
npm install effector
npm install effector-react
```

Adding the above two dependencies. It works fine.

Adding a sample of my **module** property from webpack

```
module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
        }]
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I've got those 2 installed, and I've tried reinstalling. The same error persists. It happens when importing from either `effector` _or_ `effector-react`